# How to make Sword disable when I walk into different scene

Tags: unity, c#

So I have a sword animation and it attacks enemies and stuff but whenever I walk into a house scene I want it to disable. So it only is enabled in outdoors scenes

Comment: You might get more useful answers when you add more details about your implementation of this "sword" feature and what "disabling" it actually is supposed to do and not do.

Comment: I did get a useful comment down below,

Comment: Please accept it as answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Create some kind of scene controller and put it on a GameObject in every scene. In this controller you could set a variable which the sword (e.g.) can check on load and disables or enables itself depending on that.

```
public SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool enableSword = true;
}

public Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SceneController sceneController;

    public void Start()
    {
        sceneController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SceneController") // You need to create and set this tag in this case
        if (sceneController.enableSword)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```